# Can there be recursively Reinhardt ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, proof-theory

While I was researching [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/144041/proof-theoretic-ordinal-of-zfc-or-consistent-zfc-extensions), I saw that there are large countable ordinals characterized as "Mahlo," which is a description that originally applied to large uncountable cardinals.

Other "recursive analogues" of large cardinals are mentioned in [the Wikipedia article on large countable ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_countable_ordinal). Now the MathOverflow question said that the proof-theoretic ordinal of a theory is the first recursive ordinal that this theory cannot prove is well-founded. And [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.0814) has it (if I understand it correctly at all) that the foundation axiom is relevant to the way the axiom of choice is involved in the proof that in ZFC, no elementary embedding from *V* into itself is possible (besides the trivial identity mapping), hence no Reinhardt cardinals in ZFC.

So my question is: **could there be a "recursive analogue" of a Reinhardt cardinal**? From reading through [this essay](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.lnl/1235415911), I gather that a direct analogue of a Reinhardt cardinal could not be a possible proof-theoretic ordinal for ZFC, but maybe could rather be used to come up with a notation for such, through a "collapsing function." But I gather this only to the minimum extent that I understand what I'm reading at all.

Comment: Well, right off the bat it's not at all clear to me what a recursive analogue of Reinhardt cardinals would be. However, there's a serious obstacle to any approach I can think of, namely that any candidate I can come up with which isn't obviously inconsistent **provably *exists* in $\mathsf{ZF}$**. Consequently, $\mathsf{ZF}$ can prove the well-orderedness of the set of ordinals generated by such a candidate (again, under any process I can think of), so that falls short of the proof-theoretic ordinal.

Comment: Before I try to explain my conjecture: in the antifoundation context, does $j: V→V$ give rise to a Reinhardt cardinal in the first place? I've read that it's hard to express cardinality in the antifoundation context, or at least comparable cardinality.

Comment: Depends how you phrase it and what antifoundation axiom you assume; see [here](http://jdh.hamkins.org/foundation-axiom-and-self-embeddings-of-the-universe/).

Comment: That's one of the articles I linked to, but I confess I didn't understand most of what I read. But assuming that Reinhardt cardinals can appear in an ill-founded context, would it be possible to say that ZFC cannot prove that they are well-founded? I also confess that I have no idea how it would be done, but there's my conjecture: this property would be transferable via a "collapsing function" to some recursive ordinal, *if* we were given recursively Reinhardt ordinals...

Comment: I don't know what any of that means, to be honest. This all seems too unclear to say much about. Maybe you can give a sense of what you mean by "recursive Reinhardt cardinal"?

Comment: Seemingly related: https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.07455 and https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.01127

Comment: Rathjen mentions supercompact cardinals in connection with the general idea, and refers to "shrewd" cardinals (I think) as the exact example. If there are recursive analogues of shrewd cardinals, and shrewds can be characterized by elementary embeddings, then the best I can say is that we'd push the characterization of shrewds to the $V→V$ limit modulo whatever process allows us to use large cardinals in proof-theoretic ordinal analysis in the first place. But I barely understand how this all works so I guess I'm pretty much just guessing.

Comment: Rathjen also notes that this talk of analogues is not really satisfactory as it stands...

Comment: The main obstacle of formulating such a cardinal is (at least for me) how to formulate the recursive analogue of elementary embeddings. $\Sigma_1$-elementary embeddings over $\mathsf{ZF}$ are just full elementary embeddings, so $\Sigma_1$-elementary embedding $j:V\prec V$ cannot exist. It is known that $\Delta_0$-elementary embedding from $V$ to itself is an elementary embedding $j:V\prec M$, which results in measurable cardinals. I do not think none of them is the proper way to formulate a recursive analogue of elementary embeddings.

Comment: I do not think we can reach into the recursive analogue of large large cardinals and their proof-theoretic analysis in the near future: First, we have a poor understanding of (even for) recursive analogues of small large cardinals. For example, I have not heard the recursive analogue of totally indescribable cardinals (though I may miss well-known facts.) Second, the definition of large large cardinals are highly impredicative (especially, above supercompact,) and recursive objects tend to be predicative.